# Add to cart button

Tags: magento-1.9

Add to cart button doesn't work in product view page. How to recover it?

I'm working on this template but I didn't find the solution.

```
app/design/frontend/default/ezzy/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Could you clarify what's the error? You have to add more info in order to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

First try with simple product if its working or not, if its still not working then, do the following steps.

1) Disable your current theme and set default one of magento then check if working or not.
if its working then problem is related to .phtml and if not you have to check for a controller app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php.
here you find public function addAction() near line 191.

2)  If problem is in .phtml which is i think it is. then compare your phtml with default one app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml and app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

3) on addtocart.phtml you find onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)".

4) on view.phtml there is a javascript code near 124 like var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form'); compare this one.

Comment: How can i solve the add to cart button error https://justpaste.it/6fi1f @Ashish